# 1С dropbox api: как посмотреть список файлов в dropbox?

Tags: api, 1с, dropbox, dropbox-api

Есть такой код:

```
Токен = "ЗдесьТокен";

ПутьКФайлу = "Путь к файлу дропбокс";

Соединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("api.dropboxapi.com",,,,,, Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL);     
Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос("2/files/list_folder");
Запрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Authorization", "Bearer " + Токен);
Запрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
ПараметрыЗаписи = Новый ПараметрыЗаписиJSON(ПереносСтрокJSON.Нет,,, ЭкранированиеСимволовJSON.СимволыВнеASCII);
Запись = Новый ЗаписьJSON;
Запись.УстановитьСтроку(ПараметрыЗаписи);
ЗаписатьJSON(Запись, Новый Структура("path", "/" + ПутьКФайлу));
Запрос.Заголовки.Вставить("Dropbox-API-Arg", Запись.Закрыть());

Ответ = Соединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(Запрос);    

Если Ответ.КодСостояния = 200 Тогда

    Данные = Ответ.ПолучитьТелоКакДвоичныеДанные();

КонецЕсли;
```

Как доработать код так, чтобы можно было посмотреть список файлов в dropbox с помощью 1С?

Comment: Эту [статью](https://infostart.ru/public/299512/) изучить.

Так же советую попутно смотреть в книгу [Технологии интеграции 1С](https://v8.1c.ru/metod/books/108481.htm).

Answer (score 1):

см: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#file_requests_list
пример на Питоне, перепиши на 1С, в отладчике посмотри что вернулось в переменную Ответ

```
import sys
import json
if (3,0) <= sys.version_info < (4,0):
    import http.client as httplib
elif (2,6) <= sys.version_info < (3,0):
    import httplib

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer null",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

params = None

c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.dropboxapi.com")
c.request("POST", "/2/file_requests/list", json.dumps(params), headers)
r = c.getresponse()
```

Comment: Как один из вариантов